# Given a pull request ID, how can I obtain the author of the pull request? Using the GitHub API?

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, pull-request

I want to get the author of a pull request, using the GitHub API. More specifically, I want the author's email address.

I've tried looking into the GitHub Search API but I am at a loss.

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/users?q=...
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first get the list of pull requests against a repository and then get the user name from it.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/{repoorg}/{reponame}/pulls
```

and in that, you will have user id. You have to then use that userid against user's api with access token, then you will get the email.

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/{userid}?access_token=xxxxxxx
```

AccessToken is required for accessing user contact info.

Examples:

- https://api.github.com/repos/srajagop/page-test/pulls
- https://api.github.com/users/srajagop?access_token=6848cc4a0336491a61ac93bde89a429dec73d96d